# The function stoi throws a SIGBART error

Tags: c++, string

I am trying to do this question on leetcode [here](https://leetcode.com/problems/reverse-integer/description/). Although, this function std::stoi() is not working for me and I really do not understand why. This is the error I get on Xcode:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::invalid_argument: stoi: no conversion
(lldb)
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int x = 100;
    std::string num = std::to_string(x);
    std::vector<std::string> result((int)num.length());

    int index = 0;
    for(int i = (int)num.length(); i >= 0; i--) {
        result[index].push_back(num[i]);
    }


    int temp = std::stoi(result[0]);
    std::cout << temp << std::endl;




}
```

Comment: @NeilButterworth Do you know how to work around that issue then?

Comment: You should at least consider finding a better algorithm for it, it might work with conversion to string, but you really should only be working on integers here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on standard, accessing `num[i]` on the first iteration may be Undefined Behavior or it will yield null character value causing `stoi` conversion to fail.

You can fix this by only accessing elements inside of boundaries.

```
for(int i = static_cast< int >(num.length()) - 1; 0 <= i; --i) {
```

Comment: Tried your for loop but now my temp variable just prints 1 instead of 001

Comment: Do you mean just doing index++?

Comment: @Snorrlaxxx `001` becomes `1` after being converted to integer so that is expected.

Comment: Okay, now we have the result[I] = 0 0 1 for i 0 to 2 but I need this number to be appended to an integer i.e. number = 001

Comment: Maybe you just want to print an integer with some leading zeroes?

Comment: No, I need an integer to be returned

Comment: @Snorrlaxxx `0001` `001` `01` and `1` are all the same `1` when stored in `int`

Comment: I am not sure if you understand, I need to return an integer in reverse order. I first put the integer x into a string then reverse the order to be placed into a vector, so now we have result[0] = 0, result[1] = 0, and result[2] = 1, now I need to put the contents of that vector into a single integer to be returned does that make sense?

Comment: @Snorrlaxxx Nope, it does not make sense. The values `001` and `1` are the same when stored inside of `int`. You can explicitly set the leading zeros like `int x{0x00000001};` but it will be the same `1` and printed as `1` by default.

Comment: Okay, assume x is 123, how will you return an integer 321?

Comment: @Snorrlaxxx In this case your current method will work.

Comment: That is weird, why am I getting an error then? Xcode issue?

Comment: @Snorrlaxxx Maybe you didn't apply the fix suggested in my answer?

Comment: Any idea why I get a thrown out_of_range when x = 1534236469?

Comment: @Snorrlaxxx I think value `9646324351` will be outside of `int` range.